# jQuery hide when a class appears in ViewPort

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make a FIXED button dispear when a certain class apears in the ViewPort when scrolling down.

To be more specific its a fixed Add-To-Cart button, it should disapear when uer scrolls down to the static Add-to-cart button that shows under the products description.

Waiting for help, must be easy i'm just not very experienced...
Thanks!

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RowfAbd - this is not a dup. Please see my answer.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - I would normally mark such a question as off-topic, but this is a tricky question. Not one that is easily conjured as a test. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) addresses your question very directly.

This solution will need a polyfill as Safari and Opera don't support this yet. (the polyfill is included in the solution).

In this solution, there is a box out of view that is the target (observed). When it comes into view, the button at the top in the header is hidden. It is shown once the box leaves the view.

Here is the code to solve your problem:

```js
const buttonToHide = document.querySelector('button');

const hideWhenBoxInView = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  if (entries[0].intersectionRatio <= 0) { // If not in view
    buttonToHide.style.display = "inherit";
  } else {
    buttonToHide.style.display = "none";
  }
});

hideWhenBoxInView.observe(document.getElementById('box'));
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 600px;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  left: 175px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=IntersectionObserver"></script>
<header>
  <button>NAVIGATION BUTTON TO HIDE</button>
</header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: IM not sure the Safari/Opera was a requirement... But very interesting addon. Nice answer.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette -  I included the polyfill so the answer will work cross-browser (and selfishly because I use Safari on my Mac :-)

Comment: Why can't you use a polyfill for mobile devices? That makes no sense.

Comment: U said it won't work on Safari?

Comment: You can use the polyfill safely for mobile devices. With the polyfill all browsers work - including Safari.